# Should I use 'is' or 'are'?

Tags: grammar

Here is my constructions:

> 1. How much **are** the course tuition **fees**?
> 2. How much **is** the course tuition **fee**?

So my question is, should I use 'are ... fees' or 'is ... fee'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fully agree with user8543. Just a bit more explanation might be helpful.

If someone is charging you more than one fee, use *...are fees*. 'Fees' are common in some cases as in booking a cricket ground. We do that. When we are billed, there are *fees* such as *maintenance fee, pavilion fee, membership fee* etc. On the other hand, as a healthcare provider, I charge patient only for the physical examination. That is my *fee* ;)

So, in your case, you might have just one fee or more than one fee, fees.

Answer (score 3):

Fairly straightforward. If there are multiple fees for the course, use *are...fees*. If there is one fee, use *is..fee*.